# disposable docker instance per user session

Tags: docker

I need expose dedicated docker container which expose one port (with some gui) for exactly one http user session (one instance for only one user). Each user should have dedicated url connected with his session (port 80) which is associated with temporary disposable docker container listening on other side.

Is there already any ready to use mechanism? Do I really need something like kubernetes or is there something much simpler?

Regards!

Comment: This approach is very hard to manage and I wouldn't recommend trying it.  In plain Docker you can't dynamically launch containers without also gaining unrestricted root access over the entire host, and you need to be _very_ careful with basic security concerns when launching Docker.  You'd also need to figure out how to forward the requests as they come in.  Sharing a single long-running process/container across all users will be much easier to manage.